# Python String Modification on Dictionaries

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary

I am a beginner in Python and would like your help solving this problem.

I have a dictionary that looks like this samptest:

```
{a: ['PERSON B',
  'PERSON X  Y',
  'PERSON A.B']
 b: ['ANIMAL X',
     'ANIMAL CD.G']
 c: ['CAR A.B.C']
}
```

I want to make string modifications to the items stored in the different lists in the dict that replaces the special characters with spaces and removes any duplicate blank spaces.

Expected result samptest:

```
{a: ['PERSON B',
  'PERSON X Y',
  'PERSON A B']
 b: ['ANIMAL X',
     'ANIMAL CD G']
 c: ['CAR A B C']
}
```

I have tried looping through the dict but am unable to get the right result.

(P.S. I am able to achieve this for a dataframe by using .replace()
like this `str.strip().str.upper().str.replace(',', ' ').str.replace('(', ' ').str.replace(')', ' ').str.replace('/',' ').str.replace('.',' ').replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)`)

but I cannot replicate this for items stored in a dictionary. Any help with the matter would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you having trouble 1) replacing the characters or 2) looping through the values or 3)  replacing the strings in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're asking.  You may have to adjust the regex slightly, but it should get you started

```
import re

items = {
    'a': ['PERSON B', 'PERSON X  Y', 'PERSON A.B'],
    'b': ['ANIMAL X', 'ANIMAL CD.G'],
    'c': ['CAR A.B.C'],
}


for item in items:
    items[item] = [re.sub('[\s+|.,\()]', ' ', s) for s in items[item]]

print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
for x in mydictionary:
    Str_list= mydictionary [x] 
    mydictionary [x] = [ y.replace(',',' ').replace('.',' ') for y in Str_list]
# you can add all the replacement one by one
```

Sorry  for bad formatting I am using mobile to provide this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to solve this:

```
for key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key] = [re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+| {2,}',' ', x) for x in dictionary[key]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using all the separate calls to replace, you can use a character class to list all the characters that you want to remove.

Repeat the character class 1+ times to replace for example this string `. ,`  with a single space.

```
[\s.,()/]+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/voSRml/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kyzh7r)

For example

```
import re

dict = {
    'a': ['PERSON B', 'PERSON X  Y', 'PERSON A.B'],
    'b': ['ANIMAL X', 'ANIMAL CD.G'],
    'c': ['CAR A.B.C'],
    'd': ['CAR A. , B.C'],
}


for k in dict:
    dict[k] = [re.sub(r'[\s.,()/]+', ' ', s) for s in dict[k]]

for k in dict:
    print(dict[k])
```

Output

```
['PERSON B', 'PERSON X Y', 'PERSON A B']
['ANIMAL X', 'ANIMAL CD G']
['CAR A B C']
['CAR A B C']
```